# Return more than one value from custom views field

Tags: views, 8

I created custom views fields that calculate a percentage and number based on referencing nodes to current item. So of all 10 nodes 5 of them are referencing to this item.

So output will be 50%, I also have a field that output the numbers so 5/10.

These two fields have the same calculation so to make it more lean I want to try and output both values from one custom views field. It should be possible the link field can output title and url. Is there a way to do this with my custom field. So instead of two fields:

```
{custom_score_precentage}
{custom_score_number}
```

I want one field with two outputs:

```
{custom_score.precentage}
{custom_score.number}
```

At this moment I use the following in the `render` function:

```
return $percentage;
```

or

```
return $number;
```

I tried something like:

```
    $result = [
        'precentage' => $percentage,
        'number' => $number,
    ];
    return $result;
```

But the options I want don't show in the view replacement patterns. How can I do this?

Comment: If you really want to treat those two values as the same "output" maybe different field formatters are the way to go. Some examples: [Create a custom field formatter](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-field-formatter), [How to Create a Custom Field Formatter in Drupal 8](https://www.webwash.net/how-to-create-a-custom-field-formatter-in-drupal-8/), [Drupal 8: Creating Custom Field Formatter Plugins](https://www.axelerant.com/resources/team-blog/drupal-8-creating-custom-field-formatter-plugins)

Comment: But when using, field formatters (if possible) I still need to add multiple fields in my view to add multiple values. This way the queries in the calculation are still called multiple times where one time should be enough. If I am able to output more than one value with one views field.